# Object Variable or With block variable not set when opening excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Because I couldn't find a way to increase font size of a dropdown list, I had to find a workaround. One option is to zoom in. Therefore I have this piece of code - which works perfectly. But as soon as I close the file and try to reopen it, there is an error message: "Object Variable or with block variable not set."

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo errorHandler

Dim xZoom As Long
xZoom = 60

If Target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then xZoom = 125

errorHandler:
ActiveWindow.Zoom = xZoom  'Debug highlights this row

End Sub
```

I event tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo errorHandler

Dim wb as Workbook

Dim xZoom As Long
xZoom = 60

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

wb.Activate

If Target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then xZoom = 125

errorHandler:
ActiveWindow.Zoom = xZoom  'Debug highlights this row

End Sub
```

But nothing seems to work... I simply don't know what the cause could be... Could anyone please help me?

Comment: It may be worth just double checking that you're seeing the original error and not just being routed to the `errorHandler:` section due to your blanket handling of errors.  The easiest way may be just to comment out `On Error GoTo errorHandler` and see what happens when you run the code.  Adding error handlers is a good idea, but you need to be careful in how you define them or things can become very confusing.  This is a guide I've found useful in the past https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that windows.count > 0 before doing your zoom.

```
If Application.Windows.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = xZoom
End If

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    Dim xZoom As Long
    xZoom = 60

    If Target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
        xZoom = 125
        If Application.Windows.Count > 0 Then
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = xZoom  'Debug highlights this row
        End If
    End If
Exit Sub 'must exit before the error handler
errorHandler:
    Msgbox(Err.Description)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that at that state of the loading process for the workbook that the ActiveWindow hasn't been set yet (the `_Global` object isn't in a state where it can handle the request). The `Window` should still be available though - you just have to dig for it from the passed `Range`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errorHandler

    Dim xZoom As Long
    xZoom = 60

    If Target.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then xZoom = 125

errorHandler:
    Me.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom = xZoom
End Sub
```

I would also suggest putting the same code in the `Worksheet_Activate()` event handler - IIR the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` won't fire if another sheet has focus when workbook opens and you tab to the one that you want to zoom.